# UITableViewCell - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I'm trying to implement a right swipe to the left but is giving this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [UITableViewCell
>   setDelegate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbadb85d710'

this error of the lines:

```
cell.delegate = self;
cell.allowsMultipleSwipe = allowMultipleSwipe;
cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = data.transition;
cell.rightExpansion.buttonIndex = data.rightExpandableIndex;
cell.rightExpansion.fillOnTrigger = YES;
cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtons:data.rightButtonsCount];
```

my code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         MGSwipeTableCell *cell ;
         static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"listAlbuns";
         cell = [self.tblAlbum dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
         if (!cell) {
             cell = [[MGSwipeTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
         }

         NSString *sectionTitle = [albumSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
         NSMutableDictionary *sectionAlbuns = [albuns objectForKey:sectionTitle];
         NSString *title = [sectionAlbuns objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row]];
         NSMutableDictionary *album = [baseController getCurrentItemByTitle: albunsBD :title];

         TestData *data = [tests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSInteger ID = [album objectForKey: @"1"];
         cell.textLabel.text = [album objectForKey: @"2"];
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[albumDAO selectArtistByAlbumID: ID] uppercaseString];
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"icones-categorias-album"];
         cell.imageView.image = [albumDAO getThumb: ID];

         cell.tag = [album objectForKey: @"1"];
         cell.delegate = self;
         cell.allowsMultipleSwipe = allowMultipleSwipe;
         cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = data.transition;
         cell.rightExpansion.buttonIndex = data.rightExpandableIndex;
         cell.rightExpansion.fillOnTrigger = YES;
         cell.rightButtons = [self createRightButtons:data.rightButtonsCount];

         return cell;
     }
```

anyone have any idea what can be?

Comment: Do you use custom subclasses of UITableViewCell? If not, remove the line cell.delegate = self; since instances of UITableViewCell do not have a delegate.

Comment: try replacing `[self.tblAlbum dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];` with `(MGSwipeTableCell*)[self.tblAlbum dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];`

Comment: I use custom subclasses. I tried what you said, but did not solve

Comment: what does this do "allowsMultipleSwipe " ?

Comment: Controls whether multiple cells can be swipped simultaneously

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your cell?

Comment: Make sure you specify that the prototype cell in your story board file is a subclass of `MGSwipeTableCell`, and not the default `UITableViewCell`

Comment: here:

MGSwipeTableCell *cell ;
static NSString * reuseIdentifier = @"listAlbuns";
cell = [self.tblAlbum dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

Comment: Did you check your prototype cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are trying to use a `UITableViewCell` subclass, `MGSwipeTableViewCell`, you must ensure the cell you are getting back from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns an `MGSwipeTableViewCell`.

Firstly, you can remove the `if (!cell) { ... }` block, as `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` should return a `UITableViewCell` if you have the identifier set in a .xib or on the storyboard. Having the extra block can make this code harder to debug if the cell doesn't have a reuse identifier on the storyboard or .xib.

Next, in your .xib or storyboard where the cell you are trying to dequeue exists, select the prototype `UITableViewCell` and look at the box named "Class" under the section "Custom Class". Change this to `MGSwipeTableViewCell`, as I suspect it is set to `UITableViewCell`. This should fix the problem. Here is the area in Xcode I am talking about:

[image: custom class]

You should be able to set cell.delegate and other `MGSwipeTableViewCell` properties after you dequeue a real `MGSwipeTableViewCell`.